# Python library not found in a service

Tags: python, service, debian, systemd

I've created a systemd service which called a python script.
In this script, I use the paho.mqtt.client library as an import.
When I start the service, this one is rejected whith a message " ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client".
My script is working fine when i run in his directory

My service: (/etc/systemd/system)

```
 [Unit]
 Description=My Script Service
 After=multi-user.target
 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /usr/lib/cgi-bin/vmc_sensors.py > 
 /var/log/vmc_sensors.log
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My python file: (/etc/lib/cgi-bin)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import smbus2
import bme280
import paho.mqtt.client as paho



# main function
# This is where the program starts
def main():
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found out that i'v installed the pah-mqtt with pip3.

sudo pip3 uninstall paho-mqtt

then

sudo -H pip install paho-mqtt